# Creating Linked SQL Server - server name has comma

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to set up a linked server connection to a SQL Server that is specifying the port at the end, like this:

```
[My-Server-PROD-01,5983]
```

However, it kicks back an error saying the dash is invalid. The server name is surrounded by braces like it is supposed to so I think it is the comma in the server name. Can someone tell me how to get that to work? Do I need to do some escaping of the comma? Surround it by quotes or braces?

Comment: [My-Server-Prod-01],5983 ?

Comment: Can you connect to it using SSMS? Use the same `server name` value.

Comment: what about using the IP address from [My-Server-PROD-01,5983] in order to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jthalliens - "what about using the IP address from [My-Server-PROD-01,5983] in order to avoid conflicts"

Answer (score 1):

Take out the port number, and connect to linked server as [My-Server-PROD-01]